# Getting connection error with jupyter lab remote server

Tags: browser, javascript, jupyter

I have started a course on Jetson Nano from the NVIDIA Deep Learning Institute. For that I have to connect to Nano via a browser in headless mode and connect to it via a remote JupyterLab interface. I try to login to the Jupyter server running in Nano using Mozilla Firefox, but it is repeatedly asking for a login password. A similar thing happens with Chrome, in that it entered into the notebook but continues to send 'Server Connection Error' with the following message:

> A connection to the Jupyter server could not be established. JupyterLab will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or Jupyter server configuration.

When trying to connect with Chrome, I see the following message logs in the browser console:

```
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:144505 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://fb.me/react-devtools
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:164508 Starting application in workspace: /lab
:8888/lab/api/workspaces/lab?1563387693000:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/metrics?1563387692942:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/api/terminals?1563387692023:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:168401 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:168016 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'reject' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:168016)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:167716)
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:168016 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'reject' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:168016)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:167716)
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 1s
:8888/api/sessions?1563387717828:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/api/terminals?1563387717832:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 2s
:8888/api/sessions?1563387737829:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
:8888/api/terminals?1563387737833:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/lab/api/workspaces/lab?1563387734525:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:168401 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 4s
:8888/api/terminals?1563387757845:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/api/sessions?1563387757830:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/api/contents/?content=1&1563387763199:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:45867 Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
showErrorMessage @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:45867
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228372 Terminal reconnected
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 1s
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 2s
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 4s
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228372 Terminal reconnected
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 1s
:8888/api/sessions?1563387847816:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/api/terminals?1563387847820:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 2s
:8888/api/contents/?content=1&1563387864177:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:45867 Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
showErrorMessage @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:45867
:8888/api/sessions?1563387867805:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/api/terminals?1563387867807:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 4s
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228372 Terminal reconnected
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 1s
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
:8888/api/sessions?1563388047775:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
:8888/api/terminals?1563388047780:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
:8888/api/contents/?content=1&1563388052148:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:45867 Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
showErrorMessage @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:45867
:8888/api/kernelspecs?1563388053775:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at http://192.168.55.1:8888/lab/static/vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228264:24
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 2s
:8888/api/sessions?1563388077778:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
:8888/api/terminals?1563388077788:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 4s
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228372 Terminal reconnected
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 1s
:8888/api/sessions?1563388367726:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/api/terminals?1563388367730:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
:8888/api/contents/?content=1&1563388370099:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:45867 Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
showErrorMessage @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:45867
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
lab:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 2s
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375 Terminal reconnect failed Event
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228375
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228347
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228363 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 4s
vendors~main.4184bdce490c13d11f74.js:228372 Terminal reconnected
manager.js:36 [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 68ms
default.js:195 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ default.js:195
default.js:211 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 1s
default.js:195 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ default.js:195
default.js:211 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 1s
manager.js:43 [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 71ms
serverconnection.js:192 GET http://192.168.55.1:8888/api/contents/?content=1&1563388601068 net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
handleRequest @ serverconnection.js:192
makeRequest @ serverconnection.js:75
get @ index.js:457
get @ index.js:153
(anonymous) @ model.js:231
fulfilled @ model.js:6
Promise.then (async)
step @ model.js:8
(anonymous) @ model.js:9
push.MM3R.__awaiter @ model.js:5
cd @ model.js:208
refresh @ model.js:198
(anonymous) @ model.js:545
dialog.js:32 Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
showErrorMessage @ dialog.js:32
_onConnectionFailure @ browser.js:206
invokeSlot @ index.js:475
emit @ index.js:433
push.qUp9.Signal.emit @ index.js:106
(anonymous) @ model.js:263
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ model.js:253
fulfilled @ model.js:6
Promise.then (async)
step @ model.js:8
(anonymous) @ model.js:9
push.MM3R.__awaiter @ model.js:5
cd @ model.js:208
refresh @ model.js:198
(anonymous) @ model.js:545
serverconnection.js:192 GET http://192.168.55.1:8888/api/kernelspecs?1563388602694 net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
handleRequest @ serverconnection.js:192
makeRequest @ serverconnection.js:75
getSpecs @ default.js:1206
getSpecs @ default.js:1074
getSpecs @ kernel.js:41
_refreshSpecs @ manager.js:284
(anonymous) @ manager.js:48
serverconnection.js:102 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
NetworkError @ serverconnection.js:102
(anonymous) @ serverconnection.js:194
Promise.then (async)
_refreshSpecs @ manager.js:284
(anonymous) @ manager.js:48
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/2' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
_initializeSocket @ default.js:156
(anonymous) @ default.js:218
default.js:223 Terminal reconnect failed Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, …}
(anonymous) @ default.js:223
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ default.js:222
setTimeout (async)
_reconnectSocket @ default.js:214
socket.onclose @ default.js:196
default.js:195 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ default.js:195
default.js:211 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 2s
default.js:165 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.55.1:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ default.js:165
_initializeSocket @ default.js:156
(anonymous) @ default.js:218
default.js:223 Terminal reconnect failed Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, …}
(anonymous) @ default.js:223
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ default.js:222
setTimeout (async)
_reconnectSocket @ default.js:214
socket.onclose @ default.js:196
default.js:195 Terminal websocket closed: 1006
socket.onclose @ default.js:195
default.js:211 Terminal will attempt to reconnect in 2s
default.js:220 Terminal reconnected
default.js:220 Terminal reconnected
```